# Using pandas pivot table to create a percentage breakdown of a Values entry

Tags: python, pivot-table

I'm reading a csv file in Python and trying to create a multi-index pivot table which reflects the count of the second index value. That part works, however I'd like to also have a column representing the percentage this count represents of the first index value.

My input looks like this:

```
Name,Code,Status
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD,BBB,SUCCESS
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD,BBB,FAILURE
AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD,BBBB,SUCCESS
AAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD,B_ZZ,SUCCESS
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD,BBB,UNKNOWN
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD,BBB,SUCCESS
```

My current pivot table is this:

```
jobs = pd.read_csv(jobs_path.csv)
Job_Status_pv = pd.pivot_table(jobs, index=['Name', 'Status'],
                               values='Code',
                               aggfunc=pd.Series.count,
                               margins=True,
                               margins_name='Total Count')
Job_Status_pv.rename(columns={'Code': 'Count'}, inplace=True)
```

Which gives me this output:

```
    Name            Status      Count
AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD SUCCESS     1
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD     FAILURE     1
                    SUCCESS     2
                    UNKNOWN     1
AAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD     SUCCESS     1
    Total Count                 6
```

I'd like something like this -

```
    Name            Status      Count       Rate
AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD SUCCESS     1           100
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD     FAILURE     1           25
                    SUCCESS     2           50
                    UNKNOWN     1           25
AAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD     SUCCESSS    1           100
    Total Count                 6
```

Where the Rate reflects the percentage breakdown of each Status value for the respective Name.

I'm not sure how(or if I can), add that percentage value to this pivot table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this (after your code):

```
Job_Status_pv["pct"] = Job_Status_pv.Count / Job_Status_pv.groupby("Name").transform("sum")["Count"] * 100
```

The result is:

```
                             Count    pct
Name                Status               
AAA_BBBB_CCC_DDDDDD SUCCESS      1  100.0
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD     FAILURE      1   25.0
                    SUCCESS      2   50.0
                    UNKNOWN      1   25.0
AAA_B_ZZ_CC_DDD     SUCCESS      1  100.0
Total Count                      6  100.0
```